# Why my React app is not being build on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

Im trying to deploy an React app on my heroku.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "hotel",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.0",
    "yarn": "1.13.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.3.0",
    "antd": "^3.24.2",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^3.0.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dates": "^21.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-icons": "^3.7.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.8.16",
    "react-intl": "^2.9.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.11",
    "react-share": "^3.0.0",
    "react-stickynode": "^2.1.1",
    "react-waypoint": "^9.0.2",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.0",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.2",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "BUNDLE_VISUALIZE=1 react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "serve": "serve -s build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.5.1",
    "customize-cra": "^0.8.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

I already did everything here on this troubleshooting Node.js app:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#check-for-differences-between-development-and-production

When I run the comand git push heroku master

Im getting this error here:

```
Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > hotel@1.0.1 build /tmp/build_4eca7ccd5f43b38306090c01a90cbfc9
remote:        > BUNDLE_VISUALIZE=1 react-app-rewired build
remote:        
remote: fs.js:114
remote:     throw err;
remote:     ^
remote: 
remote: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/node_modules'
```

I tried everything. Anyone can give me a light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you did not install the packages `npm install`

Comment: But locally it runs. The problem is deploying on heroku

Comment: If you are just deploying, then you need to build locally first and deploy that. If you want to build on the server, it needs all packages.

Comment: But at the heroku own page they say: 

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#avoid-garbage

For example, your node app probably has a node_modules directory for dependencies, which you should keep out of git.

As long as each dependency is listed in package.json, anyone can create a working local copy of your app - including node_modules - by running npm install.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. In the absence of other config, Heroku will run npm install, then npm build, then npm start. What other config do you have? What else do the logs tell you?